# Can I submit user editable html form data to a PHP function using POST method?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, html-table

A web page I'm working on has an HTML table that returns default values to the user as table data and these defaults are editable by the user on the page.  I want to submit the inner HTML table data values to a php script using the POST method.

A few posts described using 
`<input type='hidden' name='name' value='abc'>abc</td>`
which is fine when the data is static, but i cannot hardcode value='xxx' since the data is editable

My basic table data:

```
    <form action='somescript.php' method='post'>
      <td contenteditable='True'>
        <input type='hidden' name='text'>
        Editable default text
      </td>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Is there a way to set up the editable inner HTML to be sent using the POST method?

Comment: You can get data from contenteditable element with javascript and post it  with ajax

Comment: Can you share an example that highlights that further? What do you mean by "the inner HTML table data values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function setData(){

       var test = document.getElementById("test").innerText;
       document.getElementById("input-val").value = test;
     }
    </script>

    <form action='somescript.php' method='post'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td contenteditable='true' id="test">Editable default text<td>
          <input type='hidden' name='text' id="input-val">
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="setData()">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Abdessamad, perfect!